# Is every subset of $C^0[a,b]$ a bounded set?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $C^{0}[a,b]$ be the set of all continuous functions $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ and $A \subset C^{0}[a,b]$.  By
the extreme value theorem, $\|f\|_{\sup} < \infty$ for all $f \in C^{0}[a,b]$, so does this imply that
there exists an $M \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $M$ is a bound on $A$ under the sup norm?

Comment: As a simple counterexample, consider the set of constant functions.  Is this bounded?

Comment: @Aweygan You beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. Every function is bound in its own right but unless you specify the set $A$ there may easily be no *common* bound on them. As a simple example, imagine the family of constant functions
$$f_q(x) = q.$$
This is continuous on $[a,b]$ for any $q$ with $\|f_g\|_{\rm sup} = |q|$. Given an $A$ that contains them all, for any bound $M$ you can find a $f_q \in A$ that violates it.

Answer (score 0):

If $f_n(x)=n$ the the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is a non-bounded subset of $C^{0}[a,b]$